# Silverlight : Get image size

Tags: silverlight, image

Is there a way to get the original image size in terms of width and height of a png image that is loaded in an image control?

Comment: What size do you mean? File size? Width Height?

Comment: Width and height (Updated the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded silverlight 3 beta which provides the event ImageOpened which has arguments that can show the actual image dimentions

Answer (score 0):

How about - in your code behind file (.xaml.cs) reload the image into a new image control and take the width and height from that?

Something like this:

```
System.Windows.Controls.Image img = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
string UriValue = HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.AbsoluteUri + imagefilename;
img.SetValue(System.Windows.Controls.Image.SourceProperty, 
        new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(UriValue)));
double imagewidth = img.Width;
```

Comment: Tried that but doesnt find the sizes straight away